# CassandraSourceRelation not serializable when joining two dataframes

Tags: apache-spark-sql, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector, apache-spark-1.6

I have a setup of dataframes with spark-cassandra-connector 1.6.2.
I try to perform some transformations with cassandra. Datastax enterprise version is 5.0.5.

```
DataFrame df1 =  sparkContext
            .read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
            .options(readOptions).load()
            .where("field2 ='XX'")
            .limit(limitVal)
            .repartition(partitions);

List<String> distinctKeys = df1.getColumn("field3").collect();  

values = some transformations to get IN query values;

String cassandraQuery = String.format("SELECT * FROM "
            + "table2 "
            + "WHERE field2 = 'XX' "
            + "AND field3 IN (%s)", values);
DataFrame df2 = sparkContext.cassandraSql(cassandraQuery);

String column1 = "field3";
String column2 = "field4";
List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
        columns.add(column1);
        columns.add(column2);
scala.collection.Seq<String> usingColumns = 
scala.collection.JavaConverters.
collectionAsScalaIterableConverter(columns).asScala().toSeq();
DataFrame joined = df1.join(df2, usingColumns, "left_outer");

List<Row> collected = joined.collectAsList(); // doestn't work
Long count = joined.count(); // works
```

This is the exception log, looks like spark is creating cassandra source realation, and it cannot be serialized.

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.ArrayList$Itr
Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: 
org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation, value:  
org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@1c11a496)
- field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation, 
name: relation, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.sources.BaseRelation)
- object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation, 
Relation[fields] 
org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@1c11a496 
)
- field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Filter, name: 
child, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan)
- object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Filter, Filter 
(field2#0 = XX)
+- Relation[fields] 
org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@1c11a496
)
- field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Repartition, name: 
child, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan)
- object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Repartition, 
Repartition 4, true
+- Filter (field2#0 = XX)
+- Relation[fields] 
org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@1c11a496
)
- field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Join, name: left, 
type: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan)
- object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Join, Join 
LeftOuter, Some(((field3#2 = field3#18) && (field4#3 = field4#20)))
:- Repartition 4, true
:  +- Filter (field2#0 = XX)
:     +- Relation[fields] 
org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@1c11a496
+- Project [fields]
+- Filter ((field2#17 = YY) && field3#18 IN (IN array))
  +- Relation[fields] 
org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@7172525e
)
- field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project, name: 
child, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan)
- object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project, Project 
[fields]
+- Join LeftOuter, Some(((field3#2 = field3#18) && (field4#3 = field4#20)))
:- Repartition 4, true
:  +- Filter (field2#0 = XX)
:     +- Relation[fields] 
org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@1c11a496
+- Project [fields]
  +- Filter ((field2#17 = XX) && field3#18 IN (IN array))
     +- Relation[fields] 
org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@7172525e
)
- field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4, name: 
$outer, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode)
- object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4, 
<function1>)
- field (class: 
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$9, 
name: $outer, type: class 
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4)
- object (class 
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$9, 
<function1>)
- field (class: scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$map$1, name: f$1, 
type: interface scala.Function1)
- object (class scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$map$1, <function0>)
- writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
- object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, 
List(org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@17f43f4a))
- field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, name: 
org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_, type: interface scala.collection.Seq)
- object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, MapPartitionsRDD[32] at 
collectAsList at RevisionPushJob.java:308)
- field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1, name: $outer, 
type: class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)
- object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1, <function0>)
- field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12, name: 
$outer, type: class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1)
- object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12, 
<function1>)
```

Is it possible to make it serialized? Why is count operation working but collect operation does not?

UPDATE:

After getting back to it, it turned out that in Java you have first convert the Java Iterable to scala buffer and create a scala Iterable -> Seq out of it. Otherwise it doesn't work. Thanks Russel for bringing my attention to the cause of the problem.

```
String attrColumn1 = "column1";
            String attrColumn2 = "column2";
            String attrColumn3 = "column3";
            String attrColumn4 = "column4";
            List<String> attrColumns = new ArrayList<>();
            attrColumns.add(attrColumn1);
            attrColumns.add(attrColumn2);
            attrColumns.add(attrColumn3);
            attrColumns.add(attrColumn4);
            Seq<String> usingAttrColumns = 
JavaConverters.asScalaBufferConverter(attrColumns).asScala().toList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the error message pointing to `java.util.ArrayList$Itr` being your unserialzable bit which I think may be a reference to

```
 List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    columns.add(column1);
    columns.add(column2);
```

Which in it's implicit conversion may require the serialization of the array-list iterator? That's the only ArrayList I see so it may be the culprit. It may also be in the code you removed for "values."

When you do the `Count` it can discard column information so that probably saves you but I can't be sure.

So TLDR my suggestion is trying to remove things from the code and replacing and building your code back up again to find the unserializable bits.